Data scrape in R with cookies or other hidden user data
Edit / Update to this problem: This problem is centered around strange behavior while trying to data scrape with R & HTTR. The data scrape error can be simplified by using the following code (which is the basis of a For loop that runs through unique IDs) and seeing whether it results in a 500 HTTP Error:
url <- "https://oip.nypdonline.org/api/reports/1/datasource/list"
payload <- '{filters: [{key: "@TAXID", label: "TAXID", values: ["940123"]}]}'
response <- httr::POST(url, content_type("application/json"), body = payload)
http_error(response)

This only sometimes results in an error for me, and I cannot work out why, but I have worked out after much testing that when I open a web page to a specific page that copies the POST() in the above data the R code will often work correctly. For example, if I open a browser at: https://oip.nypdonline.org/view/1/@TAXID=940123 in which the unique ID is this trailing 123...then the data scrape for the related unique ID will usually work, but again not always. What is going on here, and how do I duplicate whatever a web browser is doing to make this work within my code? Is this something as simple as an underlying setting in R or HTTR?
If I run this same POST() with verbose as
verbose(data_out = TRUE, data_in = TRUE, info = TRUE, ssl = TRUE) I get back: "WARNING: failed to open cookie file "but this occurs on both failure and success, so I think this is not the result of cookies. The behavior here is also not consistent at all with some sort of rate limiting via the API; if I start trying to "prime" certain unique IDs by opening web pages etc, I can often get specific IDs to work in the bigger For loop again and again while the un-primed ones fail. I am totally mystified at this point.
Original Post:
I have a working data / web scrape function in R using HTTR and POST to scrape public data on a number of police statistics, but the code only works sporadically: it may work for ten minutes no matter how many times I run it, or it may only work once before it starts to produce an error message in response.
If I run http_error(response) I see TRUE (obviously when the response works, this results in FALSE). I suspect this is the result of cookies, but so far my attempts to add any code that would preserve or reset cookies hasn't fixed things. The following code has worked repeatedly to collect information on one instance, but then fails to collect the same data subsequently (this would eventually iterate on the unique identifier within "payload" after "values," here with the example ID 940216):
require(httr)
url <- "http://oip.nypdonline.org/api/reports/2042/datasource/list"
payload <- '{filters: [{key: "@TAXID", label: "TAXID", values: ["940216"]}]}'
response <- httr::POST(url, content_type("application/json"), body = payload, encode = "json")
json <- httr::content(response, as = "text")
jsonview <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json)
View(jsonview)

If it does not work, running this code in my current environment returns an error code, "Error trying to save Entity changes - The Username field is required." Yet I have seen this code work and return exactly the values I'm interested in.
Other things I've tried: using "handles"; using a VPN; restarting R; detaching HTTR in case HTTR is keeping cookie data I can't see.
Using the example https://oip.nypdonline.org/view/1/@TAXID=940216 I can see that when a user clicks a tab a request is sent similar to the above code; within developer tools I can see several cookies associated with this query:
Request cookies:
BNI_persistence = "fQZHNVs5szWnatWt8bmuAJzA1b_wBc4"
user = "[apparent per session cookie]"
Response cookies:
BNI_persistence = "fQZHNVs5szWnatWt8bmuAJzA1b_wBc4"
If I use cookies(response) I can see the BNI_persistence cookie but NOT the "user" cookie, which seems directly related to the error code (Username field is required). Using dev tools at the example URL https://oip.nypdonline.org/view/1/@TAXID=940216 and watching the network shows a number of things that are slightly beyond my understanding, one of which may be a necessary CONFIG that references usernames, but I cannot find a way to represent this in a POST(). Am I just missing how to include this request cookie? SetCookies() has not worked however I try to arrange it.

I've tried adding all these elements to my POST() request in various ways, but I still can't get past the user error--and again, sometimes this code works exactly, and gives me the data I'm looking for, but a minority of the time with no apparent rationality. Is this a cookie issue, or some other unknown way R or HTTR is storing data that I don't understand?
EDIT: How the above code works / why: the website I'm looking at allows users to query the underlying data in several ways. The example url at https://oip.nypdonline.org/view/1/@TAXID=940216 can be watched in dev tools, where it appears to send the payload listed in my code to the underlying API listed in my code as "URL". The API URL changes per tab, for example the main tab is located at:
http://oip.nypdonline.org/api/reports/7/datasource/list
And another list of JSON data, which contains total arrest numbers, is located at:
http://oip.nypdonline.org/api/reports/2042/datasource/list

My code has actively worked for all of these tabs; it just works sporadically, which makes no sense to me unless it is related to cookies or some other invisible marker I don't yet understand.Ideally this would use a For loop on the unique value in the code, but currently it only sometimes works to scrape a single time before breaking.
(This is a follow up to R data scraping JSON from API but the conclusion of that thread was me realizing my code worked to begin with, and there must be some problem that's just invisible to me.)

What you see in a web browser session will not necessarily match with what the httr client sees. The site may serve different content depending on the user agent, etc. If you are having trouble scraping the site with httr, rvest, etc you may have to resort to Selenium (see: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html). By the looks of the site, this is likely the case.

There are a couple ways of accessing the underlying API, which are also in the linked thread, but if I examine one famous officer here and watch the network section of dev tools I can see that every time I click through any of the relevant tabs a "list" query is made to the underlying API for JSON. The easiest way to access an example directly is: https://oip.nypdonline.org/view/1/@TAXID=940216 but this site will send the payload from the above code to the API URL when it wants any of this data. I definitely can move to Selenium, but it's bizarre that this code works sometimes and not others.

I'm trying to replicate your problem but the site at https://oip.nypdonline.org/ appears not to be available.

The OIP site should be the location of the API which I'm sending the POST() request to--to view the website through the web you have to navigate to, for example: https://oip.nypdonline.org/view/1/@TAXID=940216
Within that site I can see through developer tools that when I try to use a tab to navigate between lists the API is queried in the same way the quoted code queries it (with the payload).
Trying this across multiple systems and connections over the last day I continue to get totally bizarre and random results, with the same code sometimes collecting data and sometimes not.

I haven't take a close look at this but I'm wondering if this might be related to throttling issue?  Just a thought and haven't seriously investigated it.

Throttling would make sense but I've seen this code work many times in a row, then stop working, then work once and then immediately stop working--it's totally bizarre.

The answer here has been to use Selenium, though this is only a partial answer--it requires abandoning this much more elegant solution for a vastly more complex one that is fraught with its own errors and challenges. I would still love to know exactly why it is that this behavior happens, and this code works yet doesn't work, but Selenium is a much more reliable way to resolve this.
